# Clean blanks/whitespace to vbNull with RegEx

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am looking to clean up a .csv file for a database import. I am using the following vbs function and would like to incorporate '' to vbNull. I find it hard to understand RegEx. Can this even be done?

```
Function removeEmbeddedCommasInCSVTextField (strtoclean)

Dim objRegExp, outputStr
Set objRegExp = New Regexp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global     = True
objRegExp.Pattern    =  """[^""]*,[^""]*""" 


Set objMatch  = objRegExp.Execute( strtoclean )
corrected_row = strtoclean
For Each myMatch in objMatch
    matched_value  = myMatch.Value  ' retrieves text column with embedded commas
    cleaned_value  = replace(matched_value, ",","") ' removes embeddes commans from column
    corrected_row  = replace(corrected_row, matched_value, cleaned_value) 'take row and replaced bad value with good value (no commas)
Next
removeEmbeddedCommasInCSVTextField = corrected_row

End Function
```

MAIN:

```
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strShareDirectory  & "fixed.txt", True)

Set f    = fso.OpenTextFile(strShareDirectory & filename)
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    before_clean = f.ReadLine
    after_clean  = removeEmbeddedCommasInCSVTextField(before_clean)
    MyFile.WriteLine(after_clean)
    'WScript.Echo after_clean
Loop

f.Close
MyFile.Close
```

Comment: What is your question? Edit your question to include the csv file data.

Comment: Can _what_ be done. Show some before/after text samples ...